# MS Access 2010 Ranking Query comparing two columns for unique ranks

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Your gracious help on  this problem will be very appreciated for programming noob.
I've tried to search google world for last 3 days and no luck.

**Background:**
I'm building a comprehensive analysis of warranty database where I have to compare two columns of values to prioritize in product groups for our team needs to investigate.
These are;
1. First by Numbers of Failures
2. When Numbers of Failures are tied, then secondly by, Warranty Cost

**Steps Taken:**
I've used Subquery techniques to get what I want. But using this route was so slow for query to complete. (11,000 rows, literally freeze my comp at least 5 min).
Thus I googled and found this user on following thread talks exact, same challenge as mine, luckily got resolved using INNER JOIN technique instead as answered by other expert. Yay!

Please refer to [www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/ranking-performance-slow-t2844316.html](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/ranking-performance-slow-t2844316.html)

Well, except.....my query is very similar to his, but I'd also like to compare 2nd column when failures are tied, thus get unique ranks for all in same group. (Above user only compares one column, and no concerns about ties, unlike me for his/her application)

**Desired Output:**

Table1.

```
Part Failures Cost Desired-Rank

A    10      $5     1
A    5       $3     3
A    5       $20    2
B    5       $10    2
B    5       $5     3
B    9       $2     1
```

**My Query so far**

```
SELECT Count(*) AS Rank, dupe.Part, dupe.Failures, dupe.Cost 
FROM [Table1] AS dupe
INNER JOIN [Table1] AS dupe1
ON dupe.Part = dupe1.Part and 
    dupe.Failures <= dupe1.Failures and dupe.Cost<=dupe1.Cost
Group By dupe.Part, dupe.Failures, dupe.Cost;
```

I tried to tweak the `and dupe.Cost<=dupe1.Cost` part for last few days without really knowing the basics of programming. (I'm mostly learning through copying others codes and try to understand it after seeing the output)

Please note, I think I have to stick to this JOIN ranking technique, as it extremely cut down query time vs subquery

Your expertise is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

If you try to do this strictly using SQL, then your query can get massive as it has to lots of sub queries. A better approach is to use a function. This will only work if your using the query within Access, and not if your just connecting to it.

First, the function (placed into a module):

```
Function RankMe(Part As String) As Long
   Static LastPart As String
   Static RankNum As Long
   If Part <> LastPart Then
      RankNum = 1
      LastPart = Part
   Else
      RankNum = RankNum + 1
   End If
   RankMe = RankNum
End Function
```

And you would use it like this:

```
SELECT Table1.Part, Table1.Failures, Table1.Cost, RankMe([Part]) AS Rank, Table1.[Desired-Rank], *
FROM Table1
ORDER BY Table1.Part, Table1.Failures DESC , Table1.Cost DESC;
```

FYI, the Static statement means that the variable will keep it's value, and not be reset each time the function is called.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try your coding. Please allow me to ask more. (I simplified my scenario assuming I could learn logic, but now in doubts)  Can you show me how I can handle following ex.? I'm sharing screenshot of my current database. (I'm also trying to have more rank fields by increments of 1months, which will compare corresponding failures/cost..and to make life harder, there can be other additional partgroup field. [link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4lnvFfcy6lkOVZmY1ZqUEROcXM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: that's getting a lot more complicated. Go ahead and ask that in a separate question if you would. will also need more details on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Tom, thank you for prompt comment. I think I can build each month's rank queries using your ingenious function for assigning ranknumber onto sorted list (groups and descending of failures/cost)  and join queries together in one. Let me try and will post separate question as needed. Thanks again

Comment: Tom, I've tried your solution, and encountered with ["Undefined function 'RankMe' in expression]    Table field names are exactly to my example.  Any suggestion? Very much appreciated for your expertise

Comment: The function must be placed inside a module. Open the code window by pressing Alt-F11 while in Access. Right click on Modules (on the left) and select New module. Then paste the function into it.

Comment: Thank you, Thank you. Works like charm. I assume there is an expert-level judgement to use static statement to do the job. Is there workaround to refresh/reset this value? That'd end my long journey.

Comment: To reset the value, there must be a command to do so. So, your function could look like this: 'RankMe(Part As String, Optional Reset as Boolean)' . Then test if Reset is true, and if so, you can reset the value of LastPart.