# Calling a VBA Function in an Access Query

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

I am trying to combine the results of 8 different queries back into the one query. All the queries to be used are queries of queries of queries of queries. The 8 series of 4 queries split the players up depending on how many rounds of golf they have played. The last query in each series calculates the exact handicap of each player.

What I am trying to do may not be possible with the code I am using.

The function code is as follows:

```vbs
Function EHC(PlayerID As Long) As Long

    Dim queT20 As Recordset
    Dim que3to6 As Recordset
    Dim que7or8 As Recordset
    Dim que9or10 As Recordset
    Dim que11or12 As Recordset
    Dim que13or14 As Recordset
    Dim que15or16 As Recordset
    Dim que17or18 As Recordset
    Dim que19or20 As Recordset

    Set queT20 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Top20Count")
    queT20.FindFirst ("PlayerID =" & PlayerID)
    If queT20![PlayerID] >= 19 Then
        Set que19or20 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("P_19or20ExactHC")
        que19or20.FindFirst ("PlayerID =" & PlayerID)
        ExactHC = que19or20.Exact_HC
        que19or20.Close
        Set que19or20 = Nothing
    ElseIf queT20![PlayerID] >= 17 Then
        Set que17or18 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("P_17or18ExactHC")
        que17or18.FindFirst ("PlayerID =" & PlayerID)
        ExactHC = que17or18.Exact_HC
        que17or18.Close
        Set que17or18 = Nothing
    ElseIf queT20![PlayerID] >= 17 Then
        Set que15or16 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("P_15or16ExactHC")
        que15or16.FindFirst ("PlayerID =" & PlayerID)
        ExactHC = que15or16.Exact_HC
        que15or16.Close
        Set que15or16 = Nothing
    ElseIf queT20![PlayerID] >= 17 Then
        Set que13or14 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("P_13or14ExactHC")
        que13or14.FindFirst ("PlayerID =" & PlayerID)
        ExactHC = que13or14.Exact_HC
        que13or14.Close
        Set que13or14 = Nothing
    ElseIf queT20![PlayerID] >= 17 Then
        Set que11or12 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("P_11or12ExactHC")
        que11or12.FindFirst ("PlayerID =" & PlayerID)
        ExactHC = que11or12.Exact_HC
        que11or12.Close
        Set que11or12 = Nothing
    ElseIf queT20![PlayerID] >= 17 Then
        Set que9or10 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("P_9or10ExactHC")
        que9or10.FindFirst ("PlayerID =" & PlayerID)
        ExactHC = que9or10.Exact_HC
        que9or10.Close
        Set que9or10 = Nothing
    ElseIf queT20![PlayerID] >= 17 Then
        Set que7or8 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("P_7or8ExactHC")
        que7or8.FindFirst ("PlayerID =" & PlayerID)
        ExactHC = que7or8.Exact_HC
        que7or8.Close
        Set que7or8 = Nothing
    ElseIf queT20![PlayerID] >= 17 Then
        Set que3to6 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("P_3to6ExactHC")
        que3to6.FindFirst ("PlayerID =" & PlayerID)
        ExactHC = que3to6.Exact_HC
        que3to6.Close
        Set que3to6 = Nothing
    Else: ExactHC = 0
    End If
    queT20.Close
    Set queT20 = Nothing
End Function
```

and the SQL Query Statement:

```
SELECT PlayerInfo.PlayerID, PlayerInfo.Display, EHC([PlayerInfo]![PlayerID]) AS ExactHandicap
FROM ((((((((PlayerInfo INNER JOIN Top20Count ON PlayerInfo.PlayerID = Top20Count.PlayerID) 
    INNER JOIN P_3to6ExactHC ON PlayerInfo.PlayerID = P_3to6ExactHC.PlayerID) 
    INNER JOIN P_7or8ExactHC ON PlayerInfo.PlayerID = P_7or8ExactHC.PlayerID) 
    INNER JOIN P_9or10ExactHC ON PlayerInfo.PlayerID = P_9or10ExactHC.PlayerID) 
    INNER JOIN P_11or12ExactHC ON PlayerInfo.PlayerID = P_11or12ExactHC.PlayerID) 
    INNER JOIN P_13or14ExactHC ON PlayerInfo.PlayerID = P_13or14ExactHC.PlayerID) 
    INNER JOIN P_15or16ExactHC ON PlayerInfo.PlayerID = P_15or16ExactHC.PlayerID) 
    INNER JOIN P_17or18ExactHC ON PlayerInfo.PlayerID = P_17or18ExactHC.PlayerID) 
    INNER JOIN P_19or20ExactHC ON PlayerInfo.PlayerID = P_19or20ExactHC.PlayerID
WHERE (((PlayerInfo.Display)=True));
```

When i try to run this i get an error message of `Undefined function 'EHC' in expression`.

I have also tried the same query with either a IIF or SWITCH statement in replace of the function call.

I am roughly basing the idea of the function call from the article in [MS Access 2010 Ranking Query comparing two columns for unique ranks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16368767/ms-access-2010-ranking-query-comparing-two-columns-for-unique-ranks?rq=1).

Any help would be much appreciated as I only have this problem to sort out and I hope I will be close to finishing this self imposed nightmare.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see several issues here:

1. re: "Undefined function" error - Make sure that your Function is in a standard VBA module.
2. Make sure that the Module includes an `Option Explicit` statement near the very top.
3. Ensure that your Function is in fact visible to your query. It is best to declare it explicitly as a `Public Function`.
4. Your Function does not actually return a value. It needs to assign `EHC = ExactHC` just before the final `End Function` statement.
5. Check your query to see if you really do need all of those INNER JOINs. I sincerely doubt that you do, since your `EHC()` function will pull the required information from those other queries in the process of calculating the Exact Handicap.

[image: vba1.png]

---

[image: vba2.png]

Comment: Thanks for the input Gord. I am now getting a `Compile Error: Method or data member not found` on the line `ExactHC = que19or20.Exact_HC`. I have added a dim statement for the variable `ExactHC` as I realised there wasn't one when I Fixing the other things you pointed out. The SQL Statement for the query it is looking at is `SELECT P_19or20RforHC.PlayerID, Avg(P_19or20RforHC.PlayedTo) AS [Avg], Round([Avg]*0.93,1) AS Exact_HC
FROM P_19or20RforHC
GROUP BY P_19or20RforHC.PlayerID
ORDER BY P_19or20RforHC.PlayerID;`. Any Ideas?

Comment: I have since sorted out what was wrong with the code and you were correct about the joins. The code should of read `ExactHC = que19or20![Exact_HC]`.  But I still get a `Undefined Function` error. In the process of working this out I have come up with some other code, but based on the same princples, to do the calculations from scratch which runs fine and quickly but reruns again after a couple of seconds and won't stop. I may post this up as another question.