# Function Call in after action data macro

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I am trying to run a function call in an After Insert data macro in Access 2013 and save the value calculated into another table with a couple of other values.

The Function call appears to work as it displays a debug message box i placed at the end of the code but the value is not passed onto the other table but the other values are stored.

The data macro is written as follows:

```
Create a Record in CalculatedHC
 SetField
          Name PlayerID
          Value = [RoundInfo].[PlayerID]
 SetField
          Name RoundID
          Value = [RoundInfo].[RoundID]
 SetField
          Name DatePlayed
          Value = [RoundInfo].[DatePlayed]
 SetField
          Name ExactHC
          Value = EHC([PlayerID])
```

Comment: Are you sure that your function actually returns a value? (ref: point #4 in my previous answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20934969/2144390).) For what it's worth I just created a very simple EHC() function in VBA and my After Insert data macro correctly inserted its result into the other table.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Gord. The function is returning a value as i have used it elsewhere in the database.